# Changes to backing object in actionListener not reflected in bound UI elements

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSF page which has a variable number inputText elements containing numeric weights. These are all bound to Weight objects in my backing bean. I'd like to create a single actionListener button which will re-distribute the weights across all the input texts.

I can call the method in the backing bean which distributes the values contained in the weight objects within the backing bean, but for some reason those updated values are not reflected in the InputText elements.

It is my assumption that the values are being put back in the UI elements before I update the values. Just shows my lack of understanding of the JSF lifecycle.

Can someone tell me how I could accomplish this?

Here is the relevant part of the xhtml file. For each child I reference the "newWeight" object key'd by the child object. The newWeight objects are created in the loadFamily method which is bound to the preRenderView event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="familyId" required="true"
        requiredMessage="familyId is required"
        value="#{weighFamilyBacking.familyId}"></f:viewParam>
    <f:event type="preRenderView"
        listener="#{weighFamilyBacking.loadFamily}" />
</f:metadata>
<ui:define name="title">Weigh Family</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
        <h2>Previous Weights</h2>

        <rich:dataTable value="#{weighFamilyBacking.allWeights}" var="weight"
            id="table">
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Child" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{weight.child.firstName} #{weight.child.lastName}" />
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Weight" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{weight.weight}" />
            </rich:column>


            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Weigh Time" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{weight.weighTime}" />
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Payout Time" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{weight.payoutTime}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Payout Status" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{weight.status}" />
            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>

        <h2>New Weights</h2>


        <h:panelGroup id="newWeights">
            <ul>
                <ui:repeat var="child" value="#{weighFamilyBacking.children}">
                    <li><h:panelGroup layout="block">
                            <h:outputText value="#{child.firstName}" />
                            <h:outputLabel value="Lbs" for="lbs">
                                <h:inputText size="3" id="lbs"
                                    value="#{weighFamilyBacking.newWeights[child].lbs}" />
                            </h:outputLabel>

                            <h:outputLabel value="Oz" for="oz">
                                <h:inputText id="oz" size="3"
                                    value="#{weighFamilyBacking.newWeights[child].oz}" />
                            </h:outputLabel>
                        </h:panelGroup></li>
                </ui:repeat>
                <h:outputLabel value="Donate Only" for="donate">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="donate"
                        value="#{weighFamilyBacking.donateOnly}" />
                </h:outputLabel>
            </ul>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:commandButton
            actionListener="#{weighFamilyBacking.distributeWeights}"
            immediate="true" value="Redistribute" />
        <h:commandButton action="cancel" value="Cancel" />
        <h:commandButton action="#{weighFamilyBacking.save}" value="Save" />
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Here is the backing bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class WeighFamilyBacking extends BaseForm implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3710213437377609887L;
private Integer familyId;
private Boolean donateOnly;

public Boolean getDonateOnly() {
    return donateOnly;
}

public void distributeWeights(ActionEvent event) {
    Integer oz = 0;
    Integer count = 0;

    for (WebWeight ww : newWeights.values()) {
        System.out.println(ww);
        oz += ww.getLbs() * 16;
        oz += ww.getOz();
        ww.setLbs(123); // Set the values to something to simulate re-distribution for now.
        ww.setOz(456);
        count++;
    }

    donateOnly = true;

}

public void setDonateOnly(Boolean donateOnly) {
    this.donateOnly = donateOnly;
}

private Family family;
private HashMap<Child, WebWeight> newWeights;

public HashMap<Child, WebWeight> getNewWeights() {
    return newWeights;
}

public void setNewWeights(HashMap<Child, WebWeight> newWeights) {
    this.newWeights = newWeights;
}

public WeighFamilyBacking() {
    newWeights = new HashMap<Child, WebWeight>();
}

public List<Weight> getAllWeights() {
    List<Weight> weights = new ArrayList<Weight>();
    for (Child c : getFamily().getChildrenAsList()) {
        for (Weight w : c.getWeightsAsList())
            weights.add(w);
    }

    Collections.sort(weights, new Comparator<Weight>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Weight arg0, Weight arg1) {
            if (arg0.getWeighTime() == null)
                return -1;

            Integer date = arg0.getWeighTime().compareTo(
                    arg1.getWeighTime());

            if (date == 0)
                return arg0.getChild().getFirstName()
                        .compareTo(arg1.getChild().getFirstName());

            return date;
        }
    });

    return weights;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

}

public void loadFamily() {
    if (family == null) {
        setFamily(hcbbService.findFamilyById(getFamilyId()));

        for (Child c : family.getChildrenAsList()) {
            WebWeight w = new WebWeight();
            newWeights.put(c, w);
        }
    }
}

public void setFamilyId(Integer id) {
    this.familyId = id;
}

public Integer getFamilyId() {
    return this.familyId;
}

public Family getFamily() {
    return family;
}

public void setFamily(Family f) {
    this.family = f;
}

public List<Child> getChildren() {
    List<Child> children = getFamily().getChildrenAsList();
    Collections.sort(children);
    return children;
}

public String cancel() {
    return "cancel";
}

public String save() {
    for (Child c : newWeights.keySet()) {
        WebWeight ww = newWeights.get(c);
        Weight w = new Weight();
        w.setWeighTime(new Date());
        Double weight = (ww.getLbs() * 16.0 + ww.getOz()) / 16.0;
        w.setWeight(weight);
        w.setStatus(WeightStatus.AWAITING_PAYOUT);
        c.getWeights().add(w);
    }

    hcbbService.updateRegistration(family);

    return "success";
}
}
```

The goal is to allow us to put weights in a single child and then have it evenly distribute the values across all "newWeight" objects. Right now I would expect that all my UI elements linked to the NewWeight objects would be zero after I click redistribute (since that method is getting called, and the values are being reset), but they aren't.

**Additional Info**

My adjustment of the WebWeight objects is happening at the INVOKE_APPLICATION phase as expected. The objects have the correct values before Render response.. but not in the rendered components?

From Log:

```
BEFORE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@2f6cd09f
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@10f48f0c
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@27db6586 
AFTER INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
BEFORE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
oz=456 lbs=123 object=net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@2f6cd09f
oz=456 lbs=123 object=net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@10f48f0c
oz=456 lbs=123 object=net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@27db6586
AFTER RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

**More Info**

Here is the dump from logs, where I log getLbs and getOz.. You can see that getLbs or getOz on the WebWeight object is not called during the Render phase?

```
 - BEFORE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@12d58dfe
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@12d58dfe getLbz: 0
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@12d58dfe getOz:0
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@25d285b
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@25d285b getLbz: 0
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@25d285b getOz:0
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@6c317dc9
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@6c317dc9 getLbz: 0
net.halo3.hcbb.registration.WebWeight@6c317dc9 getOz:0 
- AFTER INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
- BEFORE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
- AFTER RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

Comment: Some code would help in understanding your mistakes better.

Comment: I'm with BalusC. What you want to do is a perfectly normal use-case and should just work if the action listener is called in the `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase. No more values will be 'put back' then and this method is in full control before rendering starts. So, show us the code.

Comment: Added some example code.. My main question is does the UI input objects grab their values from the objects after the INVOKE_APPLICATION phase? I would think that is the case as @Arjan had mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was some of the xhtml. When I cleaned it all out and started simple it started working. I'm thinking maybe the outputLabels or the panelGroups.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you have set the immediate attribute on the command button.

This will cause your action listener to be called during the APPLY_REQUEST phase, but additionally UPDATE_MODEL will not be invoked and when the view is rendered again it will render the values that were still in the input components (components are stateful in JSF).

See this for some more elaborate information: [JSF commandButton with immediate="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619050/jsf-commandbutton-with-immediate-true)

As you don't have any validators attached to your input components, the simplest solution in your case might be to remove the immediate attribute.

*(offtopic, but I noticed your backing bean is rather randomly ordered which makes it a bit difficult to read. In Java/JSF you typically put the instance variables at the very beginning, then the constructor, post construct method, preRenderView event handler etc so the class reads as a story top to bottom)*

Comment: Also doing business logic inside getters doesn't deserve a prize.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I removed the immediate flag and now, the "donate" only checkbox checked when I click on redistribute, but the weight values are not reset to "123" "456" as I would expect them to be. I will re-work the getter and re-organize the code. It become very messy as I was experimenting with different solutions while trying to figure this out.. And BalusC thanks for all your contributions on SO. I've spent lots of time reading over your responses while I learn JSF...

Comment: Not sure if related, but I am also getting "The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form> " warning at bottom. I can't figure out why since they are wrapped in h:form correctly as far as I know..

Comment: Also, I can confirm that the WebWeight objects are not being recreated. The have the same address when logging between each click.

Comment: >Also doing business logic inside getters doesn't deserve a prize. - You're right! I had that on my list to remark actually, but forgot it ;) @OP: Besides the style issue, the thing to remember is that getters are called potentially many times over in JSF. Do as little in them as possible.

Comment: >but the weight values are not reset to "123" "456" as I would expect them to be. - Hmm, indeed. You could maybe check if `WebWeight#getLbs()` is called after you click the redistribute button.

Comment: getLbs or getOz is not called in before render? See Edit above.