# <h:selectOneMenu> doesn't save on the bean the value selected

Tags: jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have problems with SelectOneMenu. I write this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="listaEstados"
        styleClass="comboboxStyle" 
        value="#{detalleSistemaBean.sistema.indEstado}" 
        immediate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{detalleSistemaBean.indEstados}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:commandButton id ="SubmitModificar"
    value="Modificar"
    styleClass="botonPeque"
    action="#{detalleSistemaBean.modificaSistema}">
</h:commandButton>
```

But when I choose one value from the list "indEstados" and I submit the form, the bean "sistema.indEstado" doesn't change. I have seen that the bean property changes just before the method modificaSistema, but inside this method (where I have a database connection and a sql sentence), "sistema.indEstado" returns to its original value. Why this happens? I have tried to save the value using valueChangeListener, and that works, but I guess that is not a neat solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen when you're doing data loading inside the getter method instead of inside the (post)constructor of the bean class.

Fix your managed bean code to not do anything else inside getter methods than just returning the property.

I.e. do not do

```
public Sistema getSistema() {
    return sistemaService.find(someSistemaId);
}
```

but rather do

```
private Sistema sistema;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    sistema = sistemaService.find(someSistemaId);
}

public Sistema getSistema() {
    return sistema;
}
```

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have read same of your articles about JSF. Thanks for the answer. Well, I want to make a page in which I can make modifications and rewrite the values modified. I have tried your solution, and the problem I have now is the Bean atributes values don't appear in the inputText...

Comment: Apparently the `@PostConstruct` method isn't invoked or the `find()` method as in the given example has returned `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try without setting

```
 immediate="true"
```

[JSF commandButton with immediate="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619050/jsf-commandbutton-with-immediate-true)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Abhi. I have tried it but the problem persists.

Comment: The OP has placed that attribute on the input component, not on the command component.