# Immediate="true" causes update="component" to fail

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a command button (a Cancel button to be specific) that I want to bypass the validation of some components on my page. When I have immediate="true" set on my command button, the update attribute does not work. By "not work" I mean that the values on :centerForm:p_definition do not reset to what they should be. If I select an item from a dropdown or enter data into an input text, the information should disappear when clicking cancel. Setting immediate="false" or leaving it off completely does reset the fields as expected. Here is the definition of the commandbutton I am having trouble with.

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" style="float: right;"
    immediate="true"
    actionListener="#{manageBomPropHandler.doCancel()}"
    update=":centerForm:p_definition"/>
```

Is that the expected behavior from immediate="true"? If so, how have you gotten around this for cancel buttons?

Comment: I has encountered the same problem and I will add that all components to update are "updated" but what is displayed is refreshed. I'm not sure that Standard JSF Lifecycle is correct because I have traced updated components in specifying "#{viewController.traceUpdate()}" in styleattribute on each widget or container of my updated component and I'm sure that traceUpdate() method are called for each of my compontent that are contained in widget to update. The only strange thing is that after component has been updated, a last process seems to RESTORE last displayed input when immediate="true".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Update" will be called/executed at Update Model Value phase. When you set "immediate" attribute to button command, this phase is ignored.See below images for more detail.
[image: Standard Lifecycle executes Update Model Values phase]

```
          P1: Standard Lifecycle executes Update Model Values phase
```

[image: Immediate Lifecycle ignored Update Model Values phase]

```
          P2: Immediate Lifecycle ignored Update Model Values phase
```

Comment: Nice visual diagram of the life cycle. If yours, nice work, very well done. If not yours will you please add attribution?

Comment: Source: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html

Answer (score 2):

If may help, there's a already solution for clean input fields with primefaces:

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset Tag" update="panel" process="@this" style="margin-right:20px;" >
    <p:resetInput target="panel" />
</p:commandButton>
```

OR

```
<h:commandButton value="Reset p:ajax" style="margin-right:20px;" >
    <p:ajax update="panel" resetValues="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Source: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in order to update the fields, I have attached p:ajax against the required component. 
That ensured that corresponding fields/variable in backing bean is updated as soon as user makes changes in any of those fields.

Another requirement I had is to refresh a data table after user clicks a immediate - true command button.
In order to do that,  I have used code like:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("Datatable ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, displaying my ignorance of the JSF lifecycle. Found the answer here: [JSF commandButton with immediate="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619050/jsf-commandbutton-with-immediate-true) and here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Clear+Input+Components